# Check your word against words in a text file java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I wanted to make something for a project, and what I wanted it to do was you input a word, and it will check your word against a list in a text file to make sure that it is a real word.

```java
public void wordCheck() {
    char[] bC = {char15, char11, char12, char13, char14};
    char d;
    char b;
    File text = new File("text.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                d = line.toCharArray()[i];
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    b = bC[j];
                    if(d == b) {
                        isReal[i] += 1;
                    } else {
                        line = "";
                        line = br.readLine();
                        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                            isReal[k] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            checkCheck();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what I came up with and I'm going to try to explain it and what's wrong with it. `bC` is the word you put in with each letter being the char's. I have a buffered reader that reads the first line, and puts it into a string called line. I then do the check part which basically turns the line into a character array, and checks each letter against each other to check if they are the same. If a letter is the same (d == b), then an int array will be changed (if the first letter is correct then it will be 10000, if all correct then 11111, if none then 00000, and so on). If at least one letter is incorrect then it resets the int array back to being all 0's. Once this is done `checkCheck` will be called where it just prints out the int array to see if it worked, then the reader will go to the next line.

The issue with all this is that it doesn't work, it doesn't seem to read each line or properly check the words. I don't even know if this is a good solution or not.

Comment: not answer but can you try read file to string, then compare? then you can just paste file content here and ask question.

Comment: `Set<String> words = Files.lines(Path.of("words.txt").collect(Collectors.toSet());` and then `if (words.contains("hello"))`. All your code in just two lines :) (use proper try-with-resources for the stream)